# Managing ROCKS cluster

Tags: centos, cluster-computing, rocks

I suddenly became an admin of the cluster in my lab and I'm lost.
I have experiences managing linux servers but not clusters.
Cluster seems to be quite different.

I figured the cluster is running CentOS and ROCKS. 
I'm not sure what SGE and if it is used in the cluster or not.

Would you point me to an overview or documents of how cluster is configured and how to manage it? I googled but there seem to be lots of way to build a cluster and it is confusing where to start.

Answer (score 2):

I too suddenly became a Rocks Clusters admin. While your CentOS knowledge will be handy, there are some 'Rocks' way of doing things, which you need to read up on. They mostly start with the CLI command rocks list|set command, and they are very nice to work with, when you get to learn them.

You should probadly start by reading the documentation (for the newest version, you can find yours with 'rocks report version'):
http://central6.rocksclusters.org/roll-documentation/base/6.1/

You can read up on SGE part at
http://central6.rocksclusters.org/roll-documentation/sge/6.1/

I would recommend you to sign up for the Rokcs Clusters discussion mailing list on:
https://lists.sdsc.edu/mailman/listinfo/npaci-rocks-discussion

The list is very friendly.